Constant memory gets changed, it should give error, but it is working fine. What's wrong with this code?
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int const x = 5;
    int *y;
    printf("x = %d \n",x);
    y = &x;
    *y = 10;
    printf("x = %d , y = %d \n",x,*y);
    return(0);
}

Constant Value gets changed, even if data is set to const.
I have executed this code and I think this should give error. as I am trying to change const data.

I dont know C, in C++ y = &x; is a compiler error. Please tag only the language you are using not others

What you do is leading to undefined behavior. The compiler will be able to warn you about this, and you should always treat warnings as errors. If you use GCC or Clang add the flags -Wall -Wextra -Werror to enable more warnings and treat them as errors.

MS VC does report a compiler warning with -W3.

Conforming C compilers always generate a warning regardless of settings. Even MSVC does this and it's not even a conforming one.

@JohnBollinger The exact text says (emphasis mine) "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be
specified by means of an explicit cast." Where 6.5.16.1 (assignment) contains a direct constraint violation "...and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right"


I have executed this code and I think this should give error

It should give a diagnostic message. The C standard doesn't speak of warnings and errors as such. What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?
And it does give one on every compiler I tried. gcc for example:

warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

The warning in this case does not mean "here's an unimportant detail you can fix a rainy day" but rather "this incorrect code here isn't even valid C, but I decided to generate a possibly buggy executable anyway".
Quality implementation C compilers do not generate an executable at all when handed invalid C, but most mainstream compilers are not concerned about quality. Therefore, in case you want an error instead of a warning each time you write invalid C, check out What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?

The C standard does not have “constant memory.” It has a const qualifier for objects that essentially does two things:

It allows and requires C implementations to provide diagnostic messages when the const qualifier is improperly disregarded in certain ways.
It allows, but does not require, C implementations to protect objects defined as const with hardware memory protection.

When you compiled your program, the compiler issued a warning message for the statement y = &x;, because it assigns a const int * to an int *. That satisfied the requirements of the C standard.
When static objects are defined with const, many C implementations protect their memory with hardware features. However, with int const x = 5; declared inside a function, this would be difficult to do. This declaration defines x with automatic lifetime, and it is commonly implemented by using space on the hardware stack.
The hardware stack is shared by multiple things in the program, including other variables, function return addresses, and various bureaucratic housekeeping inside the program. To mark some automatic objects read-only and others not, the program would have to keep two stacks.
Further, the read-only stack could not be read-only all the time. This is because automatic objects are created during program execution. Space is allocated on the stack for new objects as a block is entered or the definitions of variables are reached. Further, those variables may be initialized to values determined at run-time. For example, a function could have:
void foo(int a)
{
    const int x = a+3;
    …
}

In order to put this x on the read-only stack, the program would have to calculate a+3, ask the operating system to make the stack writeable, store the value a+3 in the space allocated for x, and ask the operating system to make the stack read-only. These operating system requests are typically time-consuming, and it would not be feasible to execute programs this way.
So automatic objects are generally not protect by hardware features in C implementations. They receive the minimal protections required by the C standard: Diagnostic messages are issued as required, but the program may compile and execute regardless.

As mentioned in a comment, you are invoking undefined behavior per 6.7.3 Type qualifiers, paragraph 6 of the (draft) C11 standard:

If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. ...

As for the compiler's response to your code violating that, per 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics, paragraph 1:

A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.

Note also footnote 9 (bolding mine):

The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program.

C compilers are not required to save you from shooting off your foot if your code violates the rules of the language.  Many compilers go well beyond the requirements of the C standard to try to help you, but in the end, it's your responsibility to heed every diagnostic message that comes out of your compiler.
